# How to use a schema as default value of Django JSONField

Tags: django, schema, marshmallow

I would like to use a dict with attributes as default value of my JSONField instead of a simple empty dict.

The schema:

```
class FinancialDataSchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    capital = fields.Float(allow_none=True)  # Capital social
    revenue = fields.Float(allow_none=True)  # Chiffre d'affaires
    revenue_year = fields.Int(allow_none=True)  # Année du chiffre d'affaires
    account_published = fields.Boolean(allow_none=True)  # Publication des comptes
```

The model:

```
class ServiceProvider(models.Model):
    financial_data = JSONField(validators=[MarshmallowValidator(schema=schemas.FinancialDataSchema)], default=dict)
```

**Problem:** By default the key `serviceProvider.finalcial_data.capital` does not exist.
**I would like the key to be created and its value set to None.**

What I've tried:

```
JSONField(validators=[MarshmallowValidator(schema=schemas.FinancialDataSchema)], default=schemas.FinancialDataSchema)
```

I got:
`TypeError: Object of type 'FinancialDataSchema' is not JSON serializable`